# Efficient way to run select query for millions of data

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to run various select query 100 million times and I have aprox. 1 million rows in a table. Therefore, I am looking for the fastest method to run all these select queries.

So far I have tried three different methods, and the results were similar.

The following three methods are, of course, not doing anything useful, but are purely for comparing performance.

first Method:

```
for i in range (100000000):
    cur.execute("select id from testTable where name = 'aaa';")
```

second method:

```
cur.execute("""PREPARE selectPlan  AS
    SELECT id FROM testTable WHERE name = 'aaa' ;""")

for i in range (10000000):
    cur.execute("""EXECUTE selectPlan ;""")
```

third method:

```
def _data(n):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in range (n):
    yield (i, 'test')

sql = """SELECT id FROM testTable WHERE name = 'aaa' ;"""   
cur.executemany(sql, _data(10000000))



And the table is created like this: 

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE testTable ( id int, name varchar(1000) );""")
cur.execute("""CREATE INDEX indx_testTable ON testTable(name)""")
```

I thought that using the prepared statement functionality would really speed up the queries, but as it seems like this will not happen, I thought you could give me a hint on other ways of doing this.

Comment: "So far I have tried three different method, and the results was similar"  Correct.  You're doing approximately the same database transaction 100,000,000 times.    What's the point?  Do you want more speed?  Perhaps you should stop using a database and just process a flat file.

Comment: Why do you want to run the same query that often?

Comment: I think that without more details on your actual database it is hard to say which is the most efficient..

Comment: Get afaster server. Point. With those amounts nivolved basically RAM + disc IO will be the only relevant factors. Get a SAN and see the query fly. Or a bunch of SSD ;) to see it run really fast.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail about what you are trying to accomplish with this repeated query? There may be a better way to approach it.

Comment: or a better option is to chunk the database into 4 parts with celery workers and use a celery group construct to run parallel queries on each chunk

Answer (score 1):

This sort of benchmark is unlikely to produce any useful data, but the second method should be fastest, as once the statement is prepared it is stored in memory by the database server. Further calls to repeat the query do not require the text of the query to be transmitted, so saving a small about of time.

This is likely to be moot as the query is very small (likely the same quantity of packets over the wire as repeating sending the query text), and the query cache will serve the same data for every request.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of retrieving such amount of data at once? I don't know your situation, but I'd definitely page the results using limit and offset. Take a look at:
[7.6. LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-limit.html)

Comment: The example is executing the exact same query repeatedly, not fetching a huge number of rows from one query. How are LIMIT and OFFSET going to help?

Comment: He didn't mention what he's doing with the result - basically if you select data - why all at once. Just for pure fun? When you want to test DB engine why bother using Python...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to benchmark SQL all on it's own and not  mix Python into the equation try pgbench.

http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/pgbench.html

Also what is your goal here?